# Написать программу сортировки слиянием нескольких файлов

Tags: сортировка, память, слияние

У меня есть три файла. Как сказано в задании, они уже упорядочены. Нужно написать сортировку слиянием. Вроде все понятно, но меня смущает один момент.
Если писать сортировку слиянием, как демонстрируется например в Википедии, то мне нужно слить все три файла в один массив и отправить на обработку алгоритму. Тогда такому алгоритму все равно, отсортированы ли целые числа в файле или нет.
Или лучше сделать слияние? Тогда каждый файл это как отдельный массив. И раз он упорядочен, то быстрее и проще, как мне кажется, сделать обычное слияние, а не сливать все три файла в один массив используя List например.
Ещё есть момент с памятью. То есть мой алгоритм должен быть устойчив к большим объемам файлов. Как я понимаю, нужно как-то сливать массивы по частям, потом часть записывать, потом снова сливать, потом часть до записать в файл и т.д., верно?

Comment: Да, вы все правильно поняли. Вам нужна не полная сортировка слиянием, а только часть ее - слияние двух массивов (файлов в вашем случае). Если смотрите [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC), то вам нужна часть алгоритма начиная с пункта 3.1

Comment: Спасибо за помощь